# Is there any sort of list of Roman senators?

Tags: ancient-history, political-history, roman-republic

I am looking for records on Roman senators (specifically around 100 B.C., around the time Caesar was born)
Googling for it I only find various Wikipedia articles on how the Roman senate worked, but no real list of names of the Roman senators.

My question is:
Is there any sort of list of Roman senators available?

Comment: Rank and Participation in the Republican Senate (Francis X. Ryan) contains a list of senators known too have spoken 219-43 BC with date and source (many senator did not speak, and this is those recorded in various sources hardly likely to be exhaustive. cannot find anything on line about surviving census scrolls or similar, which would be the best.( I do not know what actual documents the censors produced was there an actual list of senators?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trusty Wikipedia has a [list encompassing the Republic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Senators_of_the_Roman_Republic).
It even has some years added.

Comment: That's not comprehensive, though.  It looks to be a list of senators famous enough to have a Wikipedia article, not a list of all senators active over a certain period.

Comment: Correct. The best I could find...

Comment: That is a nice list I somehow had managed to miss, I'll give you that. :p

Comment: If I don't get a better answer I'll accept this by the end of the week (just so you don't think I've abandoned this question) :)